# Validate string contains specific word

Tags: swift

I have to validate last name for example if my last name it's a compound and contains "DE", "DEL", "DE LA" what is the best way to identify that and eliminate
For example if my last name is "DEL ROSAL", I want to identify "DEL" and then remove but if  my last name it is "DELGADO" what happens with "DEL"
I read that I can use contains if it is possible?

```
  let apellido_paterno = TxtApellidoP.text!
  if apellido_paterno.contains("DEL"){
     // Expected output if my last name its "DEL ROSAL": ROSAL  
     // What happens if my last name its: "DELGADO" ???
            }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the name is DELGADO?

Comment: There are many other functions that might be used like `hasPrefix`. Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) for String? Also, maybe you want to include a space in your string "DEL "

Comment: @vadian I expect "DELGADO" but If the textfield contains "DEL" and I delete the Pefix my output will be: "GADO" and I dont want it

Comment: You could search for whether the string contains "DEL " and/or "DE " (note the use of a space in the search string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the result you wanted by using *.contains()* and evaluating a String assigned as "compounder".
For example if the compound last name is "DE LA FUENTE", the compounder would be "DE LA" (as you explained above).

I also created an array and a for loop in order to make it easier to check

```
let apellidoPaternoInput = "DE LA FUENTE"
var apellidoPaternoOutput = String()
let compounderArray = ["DEL", "DE LA", "DE"]

for compounder in compounderArray {

    if apellidoPaternoInput.contains(compounder){
      
        apellidoPaternoOutput = apellidoPaternoInput.components(separatedBy: " ").last ?? ""
        //last component of an array containing all the words from the input last name
        
    }
    
}
print(apellidoPaternoOutput)
```

Note that a new variable, *apellidoPaternoOutput* is created, and it corresponds to the last element of an array generated when the input last name (*apellidoPaternoInput*) is separated by spaces.

By doing this (using the last element of the array separated by spaces) you make sure that last names such as "DELGADO" remain intact.

In this case, the output would be "FUENTE".

Hope this helps.